# Unable to get property 'cells' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I got an error in javascipt..When txtname is having a text equal to tbl.rows[row + 2].cells[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzxaX.png).innerText it show the error,but if the value in txtname is not equal to it,it can replace the value of txtname. I try to empty the value of txtname before assign the inner text, but it's still come out the same error..Hope i can get some hint here.thanks

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'cells'
>   of undefined or null reference

```
function setSearch(row) {
  var tbl = document.getElementById("<%=MultiSelectGridView1.ClientID%>");
  var txt = document.getElementById("<%=txtName.ClientID%>");

  txt.value = tbl.rows[row + 2].cells[1].innerText;

  $find("BtnSearch2").hide();
}


 <grd:MultiSelectGridView ID="MultiSelectGridView1" runat="server" Width="500px" 
                CssClass="paging_gridview" AllowPaging="True" 
                AutoGenerateColumns ="false" PageSize="10" PagerType="Custom"  
                DataKeyNames="Urid,Name" OnPageIndexChanging="MultiSelectGridView1_PageIndexChanging"
                MultiSelectDataKeyName="Urid,Name" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                MultiSelectColumnIndex="0" EnableMultiSelect="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound"
                >
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="paging_gridview_hdr" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="paging_gridview_aitm" />
                <RowStyle CssClass="paging_gridview_itm" />
                <PagerStyle CssClass="paging_gridview_pgr" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" />
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No data to display
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# (Container.DataItemIndex + 1) %>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle Width="20" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <HeaderStyle Width="20" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" HeaderStyle-Width="430" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Name") %>    
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Urid" DataField="Urid" HeaderStyle-Width="50" ItemStyle-Width="50" Visible="false"  />
            </Columns>
        </grd:MultiSelectGridView>
```

[image]

Comment: How many rows you have in your grid?

Comment: rows[row + 2] has a null or undefined value! And how would we know why unless you show us the grid ?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti thanks for reply..i have updated my grid in my question..

Comment: @psylogic thanks for reply..i have updated my grid in my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a assignment of `txt.value`, so I don't think your error relates to the original value of `txt.value`. The reason may be your value of `row+2` is larger than the whole number of rows. So `tbl.rows[row + 2]` gets `undefined`.

Comment: u r right jasmine! i try to change it to row + 1 but when i select the value in gridview it goes upward

Comment: @Jan I'm not sure about your goal of your js here and the asp part is really hard to read. Can you describe in simple words?

Comment: do u saw my updated question? i mean that when i click on search button on branch code row(first row)..it pop up the gridview and when user double click the row in gridview,the value will pass to textbox in first row..but now for example i click bb.. the selected value is aa

Comment: that is why previously my friend put it to row + 2..because we cannot get any solution

Comment: jasmine..it's okay..thanks for ur help anyway..i'm a chinese too.nice to know u :)

Comment: @Jan I think you can try to attach event to the grid row level to avoid the row number passing. I'm not sure about grid row thing. Sorry about that.